# Add jar to classpath at runtime under java 9

Tags: java, jar, classpath, java-9, urlclassloader

Until [java9](/questions/tagged/java9) for adding external jar to classpath in runtime by programmatically everybody used:

```
URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
method.invoke(sysloader, new Object[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
```

Now with java9 we have problem:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>       java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader
>       cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader

`URLClassLoader` doesn't work anymore in Java 9. What to do now under jdk9 for adding an external jar to the classpath in runtime programmatically?

Comment: Though the release note read that the current JavaSE/JDK doesn't provide any such API to augment the classpath at run-time. Yet, the better you could elaborate on what you're ultimately trying to achieve, the more the community could help you.

Comment: `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()` is not an `URLClassLoader` anymore but you can always create a new instance of `URLClassLoader` if you want.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov is correct, esp. if you can invoking the code in the JAR file via reflection anyway.

Comment: Actually, with Java 9, you have two problems.  Even if the ClassLoader were in fact a URLClassLoader, I doubt that attempt at reflection would be permitted in a modular application.

Comment: I found out what "Gradle" had the problem with UrlClassLoader. Anybody know how they fixed it?

Comment: @EvgeniyEgorov Since you did not specify your exact use case, we're just guessing. But maybe you don't actually need to amend the existing class path and could instead create a new class loader for the new JAR? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48093609/2525313).

Answer (score 11):

The [JavaSE9 release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-relnote-issues-3704069.html) read about the same :

> The application class loader is no longer an instance of
>   `java.net.URLClassLoader` (an implementation detail that was never
>   specified in previous releases).
>
> Code that assumes that
>   [`ClassLoader::getSytemClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader--) returns a `URLClassLoader` object will
>   need to be updated.
>
> Note that *Java SE and the JDK do not provide an
>   API for applications or libraries to dynamically augment the class
>   path at run-time*.

Additionally when an extended classpath is required, one can make use of

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("nameofclass", true, new URLClassLoader(urlarrayofextrajarsordirs));
```

as suggested in this [thread from Oracle](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4011800). This comes with caveats:

> - `java.util.ServiceLoader` uses the thread's ClassLoader context Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(specialloader);
> - `java.sql.DriverManager` does honors the calling class' ClassLoader, -not- the Thread's ClassLoader.  Create Driver directly
>     using `Class.forName("drivername", true, new
>     URLClassLoader(urlarrayofextrajarsordirs).newInstance();`
> - `javax.activation` uses the thread's ClassLoader context (important for javax.mail).

Comment: Ok. What in return for the old?

Comment: @EvgeniyEgorov What exactly are you trying to achieve is the actual question. If you could elaborate on that, would be helpful.

Comment: I tried to find info about it in google search. Unfortunately, I found out no any info or docs.

Comment: @EvgeniyEgorov You might want to take a look at [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4011800) as well and be definitive over what your requirement is.

Answer (score 3):

Naman's answer is not a correct replacement for what you are looking for.
The correct way to add a jar to the classpath in Java 9 and above is to use [Java Instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html)'s `appendToSystemClassLoaderSearch(JarFile jarfile)` method.

First you will need to add your Agent class to your MANIFEST.MF

`Launcher-Agent-Class: com.yourpackage.Agent`

Then add your agent.
The example below will allow you to call `Agent.addClassPath(File f)` to add a Jar to the classpath in both Java 8 & 9+

```java
public class Agent {
    private static Instrumentation inst = null;

    // The JRE will call method before launching your main()
    public static void agentmain(final String a, final Instrumentation inst) {
        Agent.inst = inst;
    }

    public static boolean addClassPath(File f) {
        ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

        try {
            // If Java 9 or higher use Instrumentation
            if (!(cl instanceof URLClassLoader)) {
                inst.appendToSystemClassLoaderSearch(new JarFile(f));
                return;
            }

            // If Java 8 or below fallback to old method
            Method m = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(cl, (Object)f.toURI().toURL());
        } catch (Throwable e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

}
```

Comment: jdk12. agentmain(..) **wasn't** called. MANIFEST.MF **has** the string with Launcher-Agent-Class.

Comment: Is any detailed maven exmple?